# Spring Boot GraphQL Filter in Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I using Spring boot with io.leangen.graphql graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter
And I have Object with

`private Map<String,String> additionalData;`

And Is it possible to create GraphQL Query to search data by key in map

e.g.
In Map I have

> key: test1, value: value1
>
> key: test2, value: value2

And I want to create a query like this:

```
{
     getData {
        additionalData {
            test1
        }
     }
}
```

I can change the library to com.grapqhql-java if it's possible to achieve that

Comment: I faced with similar issue, can you please publish your solution in case it is resolved. Thanks

Comment: I didn't solved it. I change graphQL into elasticsearch query _source and I achieved same thing