# Detect and remove from JSON object redundant nodes saving core structure

Tags: java, json

In my project I need use [google api](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#response) to collect some calculated statistic. Original `json` object fields you can find using provided link if you wish.

Project needs requires to keep much less data than it is. For example I am interested in next `json` nodes:

```
    "id",
    "kind",
    "lighthouseResult.audits.metrics",
    "lighthouseResult.audits.time-to-first-byte"
```

or

```
{
  "id": "myId",
  "kind": "myKind",
  "lighthouseResult": {
    "audits": {
      "metrics": ["myMetrics"],
      "time-to-first-byte": ["myOtherMetrics"]
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly I tried to resolve the issue using [graphql](https://graphql.org/learn/). I faces there with my first issue. I use `pojo` classes provided by google library to avoid of duplicates. I specified required object descriptions for [graphql](https://graphql.org/learn/) until node was a map. As result I was not able to describe which map keys should be filtered for my request. [Question regarding specified issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57432766/5728095) is published by different person but not answered yet.

So my next try is to use any json handling library to remove all redundant nodes that have no relation to my configuration. Right now I'm trying to use:

```
    "$.id",
    "$.kind",
    "$.lighthouseResult.audits.metrics",
    "$.lighthouseResult.audits.time-to-first-byte"
```

but solution should be flexible and configurable out of java (in any properties file). So it is important to have a chance safe all matchers at remove time to make correct decision.

As for me there are two ways left to get required info:

1. To use json parser library to be able get path to node. But which library provides similar api?
2. To build json object from very beginning adding selected nodes by specified paths.

I hope there is better decisions to reach the goal and helpful advice is required, may be code example if you have an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As temporary solution I've considered to use:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Library provides to get list of path to each node.

```
Configuration jsonConf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST, Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
DocumentContext pathList = JsonPath.parse(json, jsonConf);
```

The `pathList` is not path list exactly. This way of configuring `DocumentContext` provides match path list (`Option.AS_PATH_LIST`) without exceptions (`Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS`).

To collect required paths I tried follow next logic:

```
WHILE FROM 1 to N
    PARSING JSON WITH MATCHER DEPENDENT ON INDEX VALUE
    COLLECTING TO LIST
END

REMOVE FROM LIST MATCHERS SPECIFIED MATCHERS IN CONFIGURATION
REMOVE FROM JsonPath.parse(json) ALL NODES BY LEFT MATCHERS
```

Matching paths example:

```
Collection<? extends String> read = pathList .read("$.*");
Collection<? extends String> read = pathList .read("$.*.*");
...
Collection<? extends String> read = pathList .read("$.*...*");
```

Removing nodes with their sub nodes example:

```
JsonPath.parse(json).delete(path)
```

### P.S.

I have not provided all code because idea must be in the center of attention. Code looks little bit complicated to read in `java` (handling performance cases and make it working in dynamic way). For example:

1. Verify configuration (logic must be skipped if `nestingLevel` is not specified or no `paths` configured).
2. Result list of matches should be sorted in back order.
3. Result set should be cleaned from configured matchers.
4. To improve performance in 1st step we can sort result in usual order.

   4.1 filter paths out collection if they have parent for removing there (in the result collection).

   4.2 configured matchers should be used to remove from `path list` their children.
5. Using filtered paths remove everything from `JsonPath.parse(json)`.